# Howto stop Net::HTTP.post_form from autoencoding parameters

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to test the functionality of a webservice using ruby with minitest and Net:HTTP.

This code

```
class TestOne <  MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

load 'test/test_helper.rb'

    def test_one

        xml_to_transmit = "
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<MyRequest version='1.0'>
    <Id>1</Id>
</MyRequest>"

        url = URI('http://example.com/api')
        resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url,nil => xml_to_transmit)
    end
end
```

will escape the xml that I'm trying to send to the server as a parameter. Is there a way to send it unescaped? (I have no possibility to change the serverside code.)

This is the parameter as it is received by the server

```
=%0A%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%271.0%27+encoding%3D%27UTF-8%27+%3F%3E%0A%3CMyRequest+version%3D%271.0%27%3E%0A%09%3CId%3E1%3C%2FId%3E%0A%3C%2FMyRequest%3E
```

My test_helper.rb is quite basic

```
require 'minitest/unit'
require 'minitest/autorun' 
require 'net/http'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and what I could do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.body = xml_to_transmit
req.content_type = "text/xml"

res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
  http.request(req)
}
```